# Get Id after addpoint in highchart

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

is there a way to get a callback in addpoint in highchart?

```
const coord = {x: event.xAxis[0].value, y: event.yAxis[0].value, title: 'Note', content: '', action: 'create' }

this.chart.series[2].addPoint( coord, true)
```

After I create the marker point, I can click on the marker and get the id, but i can't get the id immediately after I create it? Is there a way to do a call back on on addpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and actually quite complex. Check this thread in Highcharts github with details why this functionality is not implemented so far: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/10413.

However, you can get the point reference from points array after the point is added:

```
  chart: {
    events: {
      load: function() {
        const chart = this,
            index = chart.series[1].points.length;

        chart.series[1].addPoint(400);

        let point = chart.series[1].points[index];
        console.log(point);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/amfvp1gw/